# Web интерфейс для приложения c++

Tags: c++, веб-программирование

Есть простенькое приложение на C++, решил для практики написать к нему web интерфейс. Вводишь данные в форму -> Приложение обрабатывает данные -> Пользователь видит ответ в браузере. Возникли трудности с пониманием самой архитектуры.

Я думал слушать сокетом определённый порт (80), ждать запроса от браузера (парсить определённые данные),и возвращать ему web-страницу.

Является ли этот способ приемлемым ? И как правильнее реализовать эту задачу?

Comment: Вполне себе правильный, но можно еще готовое что-то взять, типа https://github.com/ipkn/crow

Comment: Предлагаю генератор cgi и плагинов для lighttpd: https://bitbucket.org/sercxjo/mod_json-dev/ . Ваша программа генерит JSON, javascript вставляет из него данные в HTML, по запросу пользователя посылает POST-запрос и получает новый JSON.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, было бы логичнее для веба использовать более приспособленные инструменты. Например через node.js. вы бы могли реализовать весь необходимый функционал для frontend, а к своему приложению подключиться через  socket используя protobuff для обмена данными. Таким образом будет чёткое разделение веб и не веб. И избавите  себя от многих рутинных действий.

Второй вариант использовать web socket  server непосредственно в c++.

Comment: Наверное у автора как раз тот случай, когда для простой задачи тащить экосистему нода (и реализовывать взаимодействие с C++ кодом), только потому, что это модно, не выглядит разумным. Для примера, посмотрите на uTorrent, весит меньше мегабайта, имеет веб интерфейс. Вы думаете, было бы хорошей идеей, вместе с ним распространять и устанавливать ноду?

Comment: Vladimir Gamalian, Нужно ли распространять ноду вместе с приложением это ваши догадки. Автор обозначил "решил для практики написать к нему web интерфейс" . Из контекста не ясно как оно будет применяться. Может он хочет SaaS сделать из своего приложения? По этому, ваше замечание построенное на догадках, так же не верно как и мой ответ. И вторым вариантом я указал, что можно использовать web socket server, без каких либо нодов.

Comment: @Akalnq почему именно **web** socket-ы вы предлагаете вторым вариантом?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian Потому что, на мой взгляд, это путь наименьшего сопротивления, а обрабатывать http нативно в С++ это мягко говоря гурманство.

Comment: @Akalnq расскажите, как вы собираетесь web сокеты обрабатывать в C++ ? (поскольку это по вашим словам много проще чем http протокол).

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian используя сторонние библиотеки безусловно. Видимо мы про разное "проще" говорим.

Comment: @Akalnq а для http, конечно же никаких библиотек не существует. Поэтому приходится "гурманством" заниматься.